# Can someone provide a link to a tutorial on how to do a basic smart contract on the Tezos protocol?

Tags: smart-contracts

I'm looking for a video tutorial on how to become a programmer/how to become more knowledgeable regarding smart contracts and such.  Is there a good you-tuber who blogs about Tezos programming?

Answer (score 4):

Zastrin.com has a free Tezos course that is guided by videos on building a basic dApp using Liquidity.  Other languages include SmartPy, LIGO, Fi, ReasonML, but I'm not sure how many videos are out there.